# Node.js HTTP request: How to detect response body encoding?

Tags: node.js

I am using `https.request()` to make a HTTPS request using the following familiar pattern:

```
var request = https.request(options, function (response) {
    var chunks = [];
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
        var buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        ...
    });
});
...
request.end();
...
```

Once I have the finished response `Buffer`, it needs to be packaged into a JSON object. The reason for this is because I am creating a kind of tunnel, whereby the HTTP response (its headers, status, and body) are to be sent as JSON through another protocol.

So that both textual and binary responses may be supported, what works for me so far is to encode the `Buffer` to Base64 (using `buffer.toString('base64')`) and unencode it at the other end using `new Buffer(theJsonObject.body, 'base64')`. While this works, it would be more efficient if I could selectively only perform Base64 encoding if the HTTP request response is known to be of binary type (e.g. images). Otherwise, in the `https.request()` callback shown above, I could simply do `chunk.toString()` and convey the response body in the JSON object as a UTF-8 string type. My JSON object would probably contain an additional property that indicates to the opposite end of the tunnel whether the 'body' is a UTF-8 string (e.g. for .htm, .css, etc.) or a Base64-encoded (e.g. images).

What I could do is try to use the MIME type in the response `content-type` header to work out whether the response is going to be binary. I would probably maintain a 'white list' of types that I know it's safe to assume are UTF-8 (such as 'text/html' and so on). All others (including e.g. 'image/png') would be Base64-encoded.

Can anyone propose a better solution?

Comment: I'm a bit lost. Why can't you use `Content-Type` header and don't worry about all that stuff?

Comment: I'm also wondering - isn't `Content-Type` the only possible solution to find out wether its binary or not?

Comment: Hi @freakish, the issue is that because I want to pack the response content inside a JSON object in the most size-efficient way, I need to programmatically determine whether it's to be treated as binary. If I simply always treated it as string (so I did buffer.toString()) in the 'data' callback) then image binary data would be corrupted due to encoding. I can Base64-encode everything (which my demo in front of me right now is doing) but this needlessly bloats text responses (e.g. html, css, js).

Comment: It probably really is the case then that using `Content-Type` is the only way. Thinking about it, could I perhaps just safely detect the occurrence of "text" in that header value, and assume it's text data if so? And just Base64 encode if I don't see "text" in the value? Perhaps that would be a safe strategy? (I should also mention that I have complete control over the endpoint server being accessed. Therefore I can guarantee that MIME types will be correct.)

Comment: Uhm, [isTextOrBinary](https://github.com/bevry/istextorbinary) ?

Comment: I'm still confused. :) @Trevor HTTP protocol is based on some assumptions. For example that all clients/servers will fill `Content-Type` header correctly. If it is filled with data that does not meet expectations (some binary noise) then just reject the request/response. You only need to check if it is for example `application/json` or something. It feels like you are trying to reinvent HTTP. Plus I'm not sure why you have to put that data inside the body (i.e. in JSON). Perhaps you should rethink your entire architecture, cause it looks like your trying to do HTTP inside HTTP. :D

Comment: And finally: do not worry about size efficiency. Unless you expect to have many small requests/responses (i.e. the size of body is relatively small compared to headers). But even then only worry about that when it actually becomes a problem. Simplicity over efficiency IMHO, especially since nowadays the internet is really fast.

Comment: Concluding: I suggest you simply proxy the response as HTTP response just like you received it. If you want to add some metadata you can always define custom headers. Otherwise you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Freakish I appreciate your thoughts. However, it is indeed in fact HTTP within HTTP. It may seem wrong or reinventing the wheel; however, there's a lot more context to what I am doing that's out of the scope of the SO question. Specifically, what I am creating is a NAT/Firewall traversal scheme to allow embedded devices to be contactable from an outside server through reverse-HTTP. This is why I need to "package" the HTTP response (and I've chosen a simple JSON object for that) so that the response may be sent through the 'tunnel' (the reverse-HTTP protocol) and unpacked at the other end.

Comment: For my specific use case and context, I disagree about not optimising the size of the responses due to the fact that this architecture will be used for embedded devices that are typically resource constrained and are behind connections with very slow uplink speeds. The Internet is fast but unfortunately it tends to be a wet piece of string between the Internet and the thing I want to talk to, especially in rural UK :)

Comment: @Trevor Fair enough. But then how about just simply putting entire HTTP (as in the sequence of bytes) in body? That way you still don't have to do any special work, just ensure that the client will parse body as HTTP. :) And you don't have to worry about any headers and size efficiency since you only add few bytes of outer HTTP (mandatory: url, status, method, `Content-Type: message/http`, `Content-Length: 666`).

Comment: @Freakish that's certainly a valid idea and I did think about that after you'd suggested it. I can't help thinking though that it just shifts effort to elsewhere and in fact potentially creates more work. At present, at the other end, I simply take the JSON object and use its properties to set the body and result code on a pending HTTP request. If I send the raw HTTP response bytes (headers, body, empty lines and so on) then rather than simply using Node / Express library servers, I start needing to write code to parse headers and so forth. It's not hard or much work, but...

Comment: ...the thing I'm asking for advice on in the original question isn't much work anyhow. I just need to reliably detect binary or text. As you point out, the `Content-Type` should be reliable enough for this, and also @adeneo gives an interesting alternative also. Either of these solutions are just a few lines of code most likely.

Comment: I'll emphasise I do take your point by the way about the idea of changing my strategy for how I 'pack' the response and consider just sending the raw HTTP data. Thanks greatly for your thoughts. However for now it would be nice to get the current scheme working, and so I'd like to close off the specific question. If someone wants to post an answer suggesting @adeneo's library and an alternative one suggesting the best way to use `Content-Type` to determine text or binary and grab some points, please do :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the `file-type` package to detect the file type by checking the [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files) of the buffer?

**Install**

```
npm install --save file-type
```

**Usage**

```
var fileType = require('file-type');
var safeTypes = ['image/gif'];
var request = https.request(options, function (response) {
    var chunks = [];
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
        var buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        var file = fileType(buffer) );
        console.log( file );
        //=> { ext: 'gif', mime: 'image/gif' } 

        // mime isn't safe
        if ( safeTypes.indexOf(file.mime) == '-1' ) {
            // do your Base64 thing
        }
    });
});
...
request.end();
...
```

If you want to keep your code package free have a look at the [package source on Github](https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type/blob/master/index.js), it's pretty minimal.

Comment: I had the exact same use case as the asker, and this answer worked perfect. Gave me the mime type of the contents of the buffer! Great way to double check the buffer is actually text or the type you were told it was in the "content-type" header, otherwise you might find yourself treating binary data as a string. Thanks Kevin Leary!